# Crawling a page with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have to crawl all these results in that page:
http://www.carnival.com.au/Find-A-Cruise/search-results.aspx?ShipCode=LE&

The problem is that there is no option to display them all. So far I am successfully crawling the initial page but I can't go to the other pages. How to get this done?

Comment: What tools are you using? Can you provide the code you have so far?

Comment: Take a look at the click event handler on the button - it's POSTing to an endpoint ('http://www.carnival.com.au/DomainData/SailingSearch/Get/') and receiving JSON in response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subsequent pages are loaded in with JavaScript by pagination. You see that request is being sent to `"http://www.carnival.com.au/DomainData/SailingSearch/Get/"` with some parameters in the POST request. If you mock the same request, you get JSON data back containing the cruise information.

```
import requests
sesh = requests.Session()
first_page = sesh.get("http://www.carnival.com.au/Find-A-Cruise/search-results.aspx?ShipCode=LE&#UBSELBWf2tB4Rs1H.97")
data = {"ShipCode": "LE", "CurrencyCode": "AUD", "PageSize": 5, "PageNumber": 2, "SortExpression": "FirstSailDate"}
page_2 = sesh.post("http://www.carnival.com.au/DomainData/SailingSearch/Get/", data=data)
cruise_data = page_2.json()
```

The JSON response is even kind enough to show how many total results there are, which you can use to request the subsequent pages more effectively.

Some sample output of that JSON.

```
{'CurrentPage': '2',
 'CurrentResultsCount': '6 - 10',
 'LastPage': '9',
 'SortExpression': 'FirstSailDate',
 'TotalResultsCount': 44,
 'Voyages': [{'BookNowUrl': 'http://booking.carnival.com.au/index.asp?AIID=44&overridePageID=651&currentPageID=650&processingObjectIDList=21604&search
Mode=searchByNumber&searchByNumberCriteria=G639&searchByCriteriaStatus=go&voyageCode=G639&voyageName=G639&shipCode=LE&shipName=Legend&brandCode=CL&bra
ndName=Carnival%20Cruise%20Lines&homeCityCode=SYD&airCityCode=SYD&homeCityName=Sydney&airCityNameSydney&tDef=&tourName=&duration=10&embarkDate=2016121
7&tType=O&tDirection=R&destinationCode=I&destinationName=Pacific+Islands&cruiseSelected=yes&unbundling=-&switchPolarRegion=prd&currencyCode=AUD',
              'CruiseCode': 'G639 ',
              'CruiseNights': 10,
              'DateRangeText': '17 Dec 2016 (Sat - Tue)',
              'DeparturePortCode': 'SYD',
              'DeparturePortName': 'Sydney',
              'FromBPrice': '1,699.00 AUD',
              'FromIPrice': '1,549.00 AUD',
              'FromOPrice': '1,649.00 AUD',
              'FromQuadPrice': '1,689.00 AUD',
              'FromSPrice': '2,649.00 AUD',
              'FromTwinPrice': '1,549.00 AUD',
              'MetaCategory': 'P',
              'MetaCategoryDescription': 'Pacific Islands',
              'PortsVisited': [{'CruiseDay': 0,
                                'PortCode': 'SYD',
                                'PortName': 'Sydney'},
                               {'CruiseDay': 1,
                                'PortCode': 'NOU',
                                'PortName': 'Noumea'},
                               {'CruiseDay': 2,
                                'PortCode': 'MY2',
                                'PortName': 'Mystery Island'},
                               {'CruiseDay': 3,
                                'PortCode': 'LIF',
                                'PortName': 'Lifou Isle'},
                               {'CruiseDay': 4,
                                'PortCode': 'MEE',
                                'PortName': 'Mare'},
                               {'CruiseDay': 5,
                                'PortCode': 'SYD',
                                'PortName': 'Sydney'}],
              'RegionCode': 'I',
              'RegionName': 'Pacific Islands',
              'SailDate': '/Date(1481950800000)/',
              'ShipCode': 'LE',
              'ShipName': 'Legend',
```

Comment: Oh my god I feel so dumb...thanks a lot. I will check it after work and mark the answer.

Comment: worked like a charm. I can even input page size 100 and page number 1 and i get all the results at once